# when using UIWebview and dropdown, ios7 picker doesn't wrap the text.

Tags: ios, css, ios7

I have an application that uses Webview in iOS7. I was wondering if there is anyway via CSS or HTML to tell the picker to wrap the text instead of showing "...". iOS 6 would wrap the text but in IOS 7 the text gets ... after 25 characters.

Thanks, 
Faraz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear that's not possible.

The Webkit used in the `UIWebview` uses the same `UIPickerView` as native apps, and there's no way to customise it via CSS nor JS etc.

It looks like the ellipsis it adds in the text is the new behaviour of `UIPickerView` itself in iOS7.

If you really need to customise the picker, you should implement one in HTML, CSS, JS etc, by yourself.

If think it worth the effort, you should also take a look at [Sencha Touch's picker](http://d.pr/s9F2).